# Computing the Fubini-Study metric

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry

I would like to compute the Fubini-Study metric $g_{FS}$ for $\mathbb{CP}^{n}$ using as definition the metric induced from the round metric of the sphere by the Hopf fibration.

I tried to compute on homogenous coordinates $\varphi_0:U_0\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{n}$, where $U_0=\lbrace[z_0:\dots:z_n] :z_0\neq0\rbrace$ and $\varphi_0[z_0:\dots:z_n] =(\frac{z_1}{z_0},\dots,\frac{z_n}{z_0})$.

For this i factored the map $\varphi_0^{-1}=\pi\circ\psi$, where $\pi$ is the projection $\pi:S^{2n+1}\rightarrow \mathbb{CP}^{n}$ and $\psi:\mathbb{C}^{n} \rightarrow S^{2n+1}$ given by $\psi(z)=\frac{(1,z)}{\sqrt{1+|z|^{2}}}$ (the image of $\psi$ is a submanifold N of $S^{2n+1}$).

Then $(\varphi_{0}^{-1})^{\ast}g_{FS}=(\psi^{\ast}\circ\pi^{\ast})g_{FS}$, now $\pi^{\ast}g_{FS}$ is the hermitian metric of $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ induced on the submanifold N.

So i just have to compute $\psi^{\ast}(dz_{a}\otimes d\bar{z}^{a})$, and the result i get is

\begin{equation}
\sum_{a,b}\frac{(1+|z|^{2})\delta_{ab} -\frac{3}{4}\bar{z}_{i}z_{j}}{(1+|z|^{2})^{2}}dz_a\otimes d\bar{z}_b,
\end{equation}

but the factor $\frac{3}{4}$ should be $1$. So i ask what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Are you writing the metric on $S^{2n+1}$ as $(dZ,dZ)$, where $Z\in\Bbb C^{n+1}$ and $(,)$ is the standard hermitian inner product?

Comment: I tried using the standard hermitian metric on $S^{n}$ and the riemannian metric as subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2n+2}$ and then turning it hermitian (i think it is the same thing as it gives the same result).

Comment: There is no hermitian metric on $S^n$. I recommend you think of it the way I suggested and compute $(dZ,dZ)$ where $Z=(z,1)/\sqrt{1+|z|^2}$. I will comment, however, that the Fubini-Study metric on $\Bbb CP^n$ really looks nicer in homogeneous coordinates.

Comment: Sorry, i meant $S^{2n+1}$ as you said. I computed $(dZ,dZ)$ and obtained $(\partial_i,\bar{\partial_j})=\frac{2(1+|z|^{2})\delta_{ij} -z_i\bar{z_j}}{(1+|z|^{2})^{2}}$.

Comment: After your comment i realised that what i am trying to accomplish is not what i am doing. I thought that the computation result would give the metric in homogeneous coordinates, that is my mistake. So now the question is how to compute the metric in homogeneous coordinates.

Comment: I get for $dZ = \frac{\delta_{ij}}{\sqrt{1+|z|^2}} - \frac{z_i \overline{z_j}}{2(1+|z|)^{3/2}}$, but when I compute $dZ \overline{dZ}$ this does not give me the right expression. Is $dZ$ computed correctly?

Answer (score 3):

The Fubini Study metric on $C\mathbb P^n$
in normal coordinates $(t, θ)$, $t$ positive
real and $θ ∈ S^{2n−1}(1) ⊂ T_pC\mathbb P^n$
is given by

$$ds^2=dt^2+\frac{1}{4}\sin^2(2t)d\theta^2|_{F}+\sin^2(t)d\theta^2|_{F^\perp}$$ where where $F$ is tangent to the Hopf fibration $S^{2n−1}(1) → C\mathbb P^{n−1}$ in the tangent space and $F^⊥$ orthogonal to it

For proof [see](http://idv.sinica.edu.tw/ftliang/diff_geom/*diff_geometry(II)/complex_projective_space/compelx_proj_1.pdf)