# How is the metric in the complex projective line derived?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space

It is mentioned in the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere#Metric) that we can define, in the complex projective line $\mathbb{CP}^1$, the following metric:
$$ds^2 = \left(\frac{2}{1+|\zeta|^2}\right)^2 |d\zeta|^2
= \frac{4}{(1+|\zeta|^2)^2} d\zeta d\bar\zeta.$$

They mention that this metric must be isometric to the sphere of radius $1/\sqrt K$ in $\mathbb R^3$.

How is this metric derived? From the comment I guess it might be derivable from the metric in $S^2$, but I don't really understand how to go from there to a metric for $\mathbb{CP}^1$.
Should I somehow derive it via pullback from a metric in $\mathbb C^2$? I'm not sure where to start in doing this.

Comment: See the section "Construction" of this Wikipedia article: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4151169/how-is-the-metric-in-the-complex-projective-line-derived

Comment: @hunter thanks. I'm assuming you meant to link the Fubini-Study metric wikipedia page? I saw that, but the reason I'm asking is because (1) the wording in the *Riemann sphere* page would have me think that there is a special procedure that can be followed in this case, albeit one giving a result agreeing with the general one, and (2) even in the other page they don't really show explicitly how the metric is derived. They say it is derived from the standard metric in $\mathbb C^n$, but I don't understand how they go from there to the explicit expressions given

Comment: Welcome to MSE! <> Two facts are asserted: 1. The complex projective line is diffeomorphic to a $2$-sphere; 2. The round metric in suitable coordinates (which turn out to be stereographic) has the indicated form. Does either of those help? That is, are you asking either, both, or something else?

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/942391/173147