# What is the relation between Fubini-Study metric and the standard metric on hyperspheres?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, projective-space, information-geometry

The relevant [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%E2%80%93Study_metric) mentions that "*the Fubini-Study metric is the metric induced on the quotient $\mathbb{CP}^n=S^{2n+1}/S^1$, where $S^{2n+1}$ carries the so-called "round metric" endowed upon it by *restriction* of the standard Euclidean metric to the unit hypersphere*".
Furthermore, slightly above, they mention that the standard Hermitian metric on $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$, given by $ds^2=d\mathbf Z\otimes d\mathbf Z$, is invariant under the diagonal action of $S^1$, and therefore to derive the metric on $\mathbb{CP}^n$ we need only figure out the metric on $S^{2n+1}$.

I'm a bit confused by these statements.
It would seem like we're saying that to derive the metric on $\mathbb{CP}^n$ all we need to do is use the standard metric on $S^{2n+1}\subset \mathbb{R}^{2n+2}$, and this metric will automatically be invariant under the suitable action of $S^1$, and thus define a metric on the projective space.

But if I were to follow this reasoning, I'd just take a complex ray $\psi\in\mathbb{CP}^n$, represent it as some real normalised vector $f(\psi)\in S^{2n+1}\subset\mathbb{R}^{2n+2}$, and then define the metric between two variations $\delta_i\psi$ as the standard Euclidean inner product between tangent vectors of $S^{2n+1}$.
And because we're dealing with an inner product in a (subset of a) Euclidean space, shouldn't the metric just be $g(\partial_i,\partial_j)=\delta_{ij}$ on all points of the sphere?
Granted, I know that here $\partial_i$ would be tangent vectors attached to a specific point, and there's no global way to define these with a single chart.
Still, it would mean that the Fubini-Study metric is "locally trivial", which doesn't seem to be the case.

I can see that part of the apparent complexity in the expressions for the Fubini-Study metric (as discussed *e.g.* [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4151169/173147) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/942391/173147)) is probably due to expressing the metric in stereographic coordinates. But I can't quite figure out whether these expressions are also compatible with saying that the metric is indeed locally trivial (or if this is even true), and whether the metric is really just the standard metric on a hypersphere expressed in stereographic coordinates.

Comment: A question like this is often answered by working out the details rigorously. I suggest you use the definition stated in the first paragraph and try to compute the metric with respect to some choice of coordinates on $\mathbb{C}P^n$. It might be best to start with $n=1$ (which turns out to be the Hopf vibration) and $n = 2$.

Comment: @Deane what I'm not positive about is the exact calculation that is being performed. Fix the $n=1$ for example. I understand how the map $S^3\to \mathbb{CP}^1$ works. I understand how to take local charts for $\mathbb{CP}^1$, and also for $S^3$ (eg using stereographic coordinates). But where does the expression for the metric in ${\Bbb CP}^1$ given eg in the linked post actually come from? I compute the metric on ${\Bbb CP}^1$ induced by the Euclidean one on $S^3$, representing it in homogeneous local coordinates? Or is it something else?

Comment: given $p\in S^3$, and $f:S^3\to{\Bbb CP}^1$, I want to define the metric as $g'_{f(p)}(df_p(v),df_p(w))= g_p(v,w)$ for $v,w\in T_p S^3$. In local coordinates, I guess I'll  want to write $g'_{f(p)}(\partial,\partial)$, with $\partial$ the normalized tangent vector in ${\Bbb CP}^1$. So I pull this back through $f$ and obtain some tangent vector in $T_p S^3$, the length of which I compute via $g_p$? I guess I'll try this and see if I get the correct result

Comment: To be honest, it's been a very very long time since I've done this calculation, so I do not remember. Just keep trying different ways. Here is one possible attempt:
$$(z^1,\dots,z^n)=e^{i\theta}(r^1e^{i\theta^1},\dots,r^ne^{i\theta^n}),$$
where $$\theta^1+\cdots+\theta^n=0.$$
Then try to write $$g=|dz^1|^2+\cdots+|dz^n|^2$$ as something like $$g=dr^2+r^2\,d\theta^2+(\ldots),$$ where $r=(r^1)^2+\cdots+(r^n)^2$ and the third term does not contain $dr$ or $d\theta$. Then the Fubini-Study metric is the third term restricted to $r=1$.